# React - show/hide element on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React hooks, I have 2 components:

1. Curtain
2. Navbar

Here is my code for the `Curtain` component:

```js
    function Curtain(){

    return(
        <div className="curtain__div">
            <ul className="menu__items">
                <li className="about">abc</li>
                <li>def</li>
                <li>ghi</li>
                <li>klm</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Curtain;
```

Here is my code for the `NavBar` component:

```js
    function NavBar(){

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


    return(
        <nav className="nav__bar">
           
            <ul className="menu">
               <li className="menu__icon" onClick={() => setShow(true)}><box-icon name='menu' color="floralwhite" size="md"/>
               <Curtain/>
             </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );

}


export default NavBar;
```

My Question:
I want to show the `Curtain` component, when the user click on the li which is of `className="menu__icon"`, and to be hidden when the user clicks on it again.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest option is just to return the component conditionally based on your state:

```
return(
  <nav className="nav__bar">
    <ul className="menu">
      <li className="menu__icon" onClick={() => setShow(currentShow => !currentShow)}>
        <box-icon name='menu' color="floralwhite" size="md"/>
        { show ? <Curtain/> : null }
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
);
```

To toggle the `show` off again, you can change

```
onClick={() => setShow(true)}
```

to instead invert the current state like this:

```
onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
// or
onClick={() => setShow(currentShow => !currentShow)}
```

(The second option is technically better as it avoids race conditions if you were to repeatedly click the button very quickly)

Answer (score 2):

First, currently you're only ever setting the state to "show" the component, never to "hide" it:

```
onClick={() => setShow(true)}
```

Instead of always setting the state to `true`, toggle the state from whatever its current value is:

```
onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
```

Second, you would use that state value to conditionally render the element.  So instead of always rendering it:

```
<Curtain/>
```

You would conditionally render it based on state:

```
{ show ? <Curtain/> : null }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the state of show as a prop to curtain.

Then you can conditionally show/hide using classname or something.

Also, in setShow, pass the value where it could be true or false by prefixing with a !. There you are passing true or false.

```
function NavBar(){

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


return(
    <nav className="nav__bar">
       
        <ul className="menu">
           <li className="menu__icon" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}><box-icon name='menu' color="floralwhite" size="md"/>
           <Curtain show={show}/>
         </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);
```

Then in the curtain component, you can do something like this:

```
function Curtain(props){

return(
    <div className="curtain__div">
        <ul className="menu__items">
            <li className={props.show ? 'show-class' : 'hide-class'}>abc</li>
            <li>def</li>
            <li>ghi</li>
            <li>klm</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your handle function to toggle, rather than always setting true - this should do the trick

```
function NavBar(){

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


return(
    <nav className="nav__bar">
       
        <ul className="menu">
           <li className="menu__icon" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}><box-icon name='menu' color="floralwhite" size="md"/>
           <Curtain/>
         </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);

}


export default NavBar;
```